# GET request to port 81 using axios (or even js native fetch)

Tags: axios

I have a Node.js API running on port 81, and want to hit the endpoint from JavaScript like this:

```js
function fetchFromApi() {
    const axios = require('axios');
    console.log('using port 81',axios.defaults);
    axios.request({
        method: 'get',
        url:'/api/getAccountList',
        port: 81, // port options is not valid - this does not have the desired result
    })
    .then( response => {
        console.log(response);
        const data = response.data;
        const errors = (data.errors) ? data.errors : false;
        if (errors) {
            setErrors(errors);
        }
    })
    .catch( reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });
}
```

The network tab in chrome developer tools show this request still went to port 80.

When I try to code the entire protocol, port, host and url in the `axios` request, I get a CORS error:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/getAccountList')
```

Error is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:81/api/getAccountList'
>   from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

My API server is a simple Node.js server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 81;
app.get('/api/getAccountList', (req, res) => {
    const userIdBy = req.params.userIdBy;
    const apiToken = req.params.apiToken;

    if (!(userIdBy && apiToken)) {
        res.status(200).json({errors:['Missing credentials']});
        return true;
    }
    // check the user id and api token match up:
    console.log('Hello');
});
app.listen(port);
```

How can I make my client query the API using HTTP on port 81?

Answer (score 2):

CORS is a security feature in most browsers that disables cross-origin requests—i.e., requests from a different hostname. To surpass it, install the `cors` dependency on your Express server via `npm` using:

```sh
npm install cors
```

Then you need to add it to every app via the `cors()` function to every `{{httpMethod}}` you want to allow other domains to make requests to.

Try editing your code like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const port = 81;

app.get('/api/getAccountList', cors(), (req, res)=>{})
```

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, to get Axios to GET from port 81 on the same host as the javascript is running I used:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
//...
//...
axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":81";
const result = await axios('/your/endpoint');
//...
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this to your Node.js server?

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:81');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

You can try to add only `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header or modify others to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I understand this is one approach. I would prefer to tell the axios to query on a different port (only) instead of generating a url lilke this. I like how I can just put the path (```/api/getAccountList```) in the axios get and it will work across my local dev, uat and live. Any chance you know how to make axios not use the default port 80 and leave everything else unchanged?

Comment: @NULLpointer, you can read about that issue here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/187 and here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1794  .

Comment: Thanks @webprogrammer - it appears I am not Marco Polo here. After reading  github.com/axios/axios/issues/187 I don't think Axios are about to include this in their code either. will try ```axios.defaults.port = 8080;``` but also will look if fetch() allows me to specify only the port.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the required CORS protection AND avoid hard coding the servers FQDN / hostname, I used this code in my node api server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const apiProviderPort = 81;
const allowedApiConsumerPort = 80;

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  const host = req.get('host'); // NOTE host is the fqdn:port
  const hostSplit = host.split(':');
  var fqdn;
  if (hostSplit.length == 1) {
    // I am not sure this is needed, it will be if hostname is fqdn[:port]
    fqdn = host;
  } else if (hostSplit.length == 2) {
    fqdn = hostSplit[0];
  } else {
    console.log('Error the host contained multiple colons!');
  }
  console.log('protocol:',req.protocol,'host:',host,'fqdn:' + fqdn);
  // next line edited March 2020 - I changed + '//' + to + '//:' +
  // as the developer tools console showed
  // The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'http//localhost:3000'.
  const allowableOrigin = req.protocol + '//' + fqdn + ':' + allowedApiConsumerPort;
  console.log('allowableOrigin:',allowableOrigin)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', allowableOrigin);
  next();
});
app.get('/api/userDocReportData/', (req, res) => {
  const userIdBy = req.params.userIdBy;
  const apiToken = req.params.apiToken;

  if (!(userIdBy && apiToken)) {
    res.status(200).json({errors:['Missing credentials']});
    return true;
  }
  // check the user id and api token match up:
  // ...
  // get your payload etc
  res.status(200).json({errors:false,payload:{} });
});
app.listen(apiProviderPort);
```

I enhanced @webprogrammers answer above as I wanted code that could work in any environment (localhost; test.example.com, live.example.com etc)